# Is the Sony PCM-M10 suitable with Rode NTG-2?

Tags: rode, sony, pcm-m10, ntg2

I've recently bought the [Sony - PCM-M10](http://www.sony.fr/pro/product/broadcast-products-professional-audio-portable/pcm-m10/overview/) as an external recorder to accompany my [Sony a6000](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/sony-alpha-a6000) camera which doesn't have any external microphone input.

While I really like the sound of the build-in mics on the PCM-M10 I decided to buy a shotgun mic. After listening to the comparison here: http://www.newmediascholar.net/tester/ I decided to go with the [Rode - NTG-2](http://www.rode.com/microphones/ntg-2).

I bought a second hand one and couldn't try it out as it was from a guy from different part of the country.

Now I am quite disappointed. To get usable sound with the Rode NTG-2 (with a fresh battery) plugged into the PCM-M10 via XLR - 3.5mm jack cable I have to use the 'High Mic Sensitivity' on the recorder a then it is significantly noisier then the PCM-M10's built-in mics. Also (the hiss aside) it sounds muffled and overall much worse than the standalone PCM-M10.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it just not a suitable mic for the PCM-M-10?

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1):

2 possibilities I think, 1 is the XLR to 1/8 Cable may not be original and therefore not wired correctly , (XRL pin 1+3 wired to ground , Pin 2 goes to a Blocking Capacitor that is wired to Tip and Ring of the 1/8" TRS )

Or the Mic is bad , I have the NTG-2 , and also NTG-3 so I know what they sound like , and Muffled they are not . Direct to Camera the NTG-2 is decent for run and gun location work , where I am close up to the target . 
So The Sony M10 should not have issues with that mic .

Try - Menu , Setting , Input Plug In Power OFF , see what happens 
Try - Cable test , with multi meter , Pin 2 of XLR , should register on Tip and Ring of TRS plug ( TRS means Tip Ring Sleeve , sleeve being ground .)